# Forcing fwrite to use \n instead of \r\n in PHP

Tags: php, linux, fopen, fwrite

I'm running PHP on a Linux server and I'm generating bash scripts for use on a Mac computer with PHP's fopen/fwrite. It's working fine except the line endings are being written as \r\n instead of just \n, which causes error when I try to run the script on the Mac.

How can I force fwrite to use \n instead of \r\n for line endings? I've tried utf8_encoding my text and forcing binary mode but I can't seem to figure it out!

```
   $scriptFile = "/path/to/my/script.sh";
   $fh = fopen($scriptFile, 'w');
   fwrite($fh, "$script");
   fclose($fh);
```

$script is the content from a text field in mysql, and looks a bit like this, typically:

```
   # comment
   echo "numphotos 1"

   # comment
   /opt/local/bin/gphoto2 --capture-image-and-download -F 1 

   # comment
   echo "696969"
```

Comment: can you share some code?  I'm assuming you are using a hard coded value to delineate your line end convention?  Since fwrite itself writes directly to the stream what it receives.

Comment: `fwrite($fh, str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $script));` ?

Comment: @DaanTimmer I just did that actually, and it totally worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Nick provided as an answer :-)

Comment: I've just seen the question update. It doesn't make much sense to store bash code using Windows line feeds. You should consider fixing the problem rather than adding a workaround.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario my teach always told me not to alter data that goes in the database, and only alter the data that goes out of it. If it is running on a Linux machine, and using windows to interface the website. While running the output on a MAC should mean that the linux interface should alter the data that goes out and adapt it to the target machine once it generates the content for it. Thus this does seem good practice to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Somewhere in your code, you're writing the line endings yourself, because fwrite() doesn't put them in for you. Instead of writing "\r" or "\n" or "\r\n", change the code to use PHP_EOL instead... this will write the appropriate line endings for the operating system on which the PHP script is running.

Comment: This should really be the correct answer here, fwrite has nothing to do with the line ending convetion.  This is in the code somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

`fwrite()` does not add line feeds to your text. Windows line feeds are there because you write them yourself, either directly:

```
fwrite($fp, "Foo\r\nBar");
```

... or indirectly:

```
// Source code saved on Windows
fwrite($fp, 'Foo
Bar');
```

So your only option is basically to change line feeds to the desired style.

Even if you open the file as text (I assume you meant that and not binary) the line feed translation only works when PHP runs on Windows (see the note at http://es2.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

Answer (score 0):

This would be the way to go:

```
fwrite($fh, str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $script));
```

Comment: So, just to be curious, who downvoted this almost three years later? xD